# Python: the end of the day using 24hr clock for datetime module

Tags: python, datetime

I'm using `datetime` module. I was told that 24:00:00 is a ValueError
cause the hour is range from 00 to 23. So what time is the end of
the day in 24hr clock?

---------Edited----------

Up to now I prefer Gord's answer. Though Igor has a very practical one.

My question is what's the very last time of `datetime` module. Since it has a resolution of microseconds. Gord's answer is the most accurate.

Comment: I don't really know about `datetime`, but the end of the day is 23:59:59. 00:00 (=24:00) is the beginning of the next day.

Comment: Very interesting question! It sounds somewhat trivial, but it isn't so clear what is the beginning and what the end of the day. At first look I'd say (in  general, not concerning programming in particular) 00:00:00 should be the end and 00:00:01 should be the beginning of the day. But maybe I'm completely wrong.

Comment: 0 is the very start -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`datetime` objects have a resolution of microseconds, so the last possible time value for a given day would be 23:59:59.999999. That is

hours: 23
minutes: 59
seconds: 59
microseconds: 999999

So, if you have a `datetime`, you can set it to the end of the day using the replace method:

```
import datetime

now_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
end_of_day_datetime = now_datetime.replace(hour=23, minute=59, second=59, microsecond=999999)
```

Answer (score 7):

Get the beginning of the next day and substract 1 microsecond:

```
import datetime

source_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
eod = datetime.datetime(
    year=source_datetime.year,
    month=source_datetime.month,
    day=source_datetime.day
) + datetime.timedelta(days=1, microseconds=-1)

print(eod)  # 2016-01-04 23:59:59.999999
```

Comment: The last microsecond of the previous day is not the same as the first microsecond of the following day.

Answer (score 2):

There is no 24:00:00 in practice. After 23:59:59 there is 0:00:00

Comment: ISO 8601 allows for 24:00 to represent 00:00:00 of the following day.  It is also much more convenient for users to request a report "from 00:00:00 till "24:00:00" on a day rather than >= 00:00:00 AND < 00:00:00-the-following-day